# Trying to build directory, file movement related JFrame program. Problem inside

Tags: java, file, file-io

So the point of the program is to take all files from a main directory and target specific file extensions in every folder in that directory and move those files to their own respective folders, named after the file name.

Example- choose the My Documents directory and it looks through all files and folders in there and targets the file extension of my choosing like a .txt file.

It takes all .txt files and puts them in their own folder. Example1.txt is put in Example1 folder, Example2.txt is put into Example2 folder etc. etc. But it has to go through all the folders that are in My Documents as well.

I don't know library exists if there's something like that or if there's already a method out there that does something like that. I can find the file moving method but that's about it.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Use `File.listFiles(…)` to get a list of files in a directory.

Comment: This is a very common idea buty I dont think using java is the best way to solve this, maybe changing this question to a scripting language would be better (python, powershell etc), also please share what you've done so far.

Comment: I haven't made the JFrame yet because I wasn't sure if Java was the appropriate language to be using here. I also thought of using a script in cmd but liked the idea of turning it into a program with JFrame. I am newly self taught and this was just an idea I had to help sort some stuff for me better. Thank you for the responses so far